# How to render HTML in PowerShell without using MSIE or writing to a file?

Tags: html, .net, powershell, xaml

I'm looking for a terse way to render the display of an HTML string in PowerShell without using MSIE or writing the result to a file.

Is there a way to do it using WebBrowser within XAML?

When I try that, the WebBrowser doesn't seem to have a DocumentText or Document.Text member to be set to the desired text.

You can specify a source, so I've tried a Data URL as the source, but WebBrowser doesn't seem to support Data URLs as the source.

It would be great if the HTML could somehow be inline in the XAML or sent to the browser as a property for the document text.

- I don't want to write to a file. I know how to do that but consider it bad practice.
- I don't want to rely on MSIE, as MS abandoned t and doesn't recommend using it for anything anymore.
  I don't mind using Add-Type to call upon something like VB or C# if the code is minimal.
- I don't want to download any special software. I want to know how to do it with PowerShell. his just seems so basic you'd think there'd be a builtin Show-HTML Cmdlet for that as easy as ogv. (after all, there's plenty of commands that convert to html or produce html as a string)

There was an answer to a similar question here on stack overflow years ago that suggested MSIE as an answer, but now that MSIE is deprecated and abandoned, that is no longer an option. And surely PS, XAML and .net have advanced since then.

Comment: My goal here is to replace bginfo with some simple queries using CIM and providing the details when you click on a tray icon.

Comment: What's so bad about writing HTML to a temp file and open it in the default browser?

Comment: Bad practice. e.g. if the process is terminated while the file exists it leaves trash around.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply embed your XAML in PowerShell and go from there.

#### (dynamic) PowerShell BGInfo Example:

```
[CmdletBinding()]param(
    [TimeSpan]$RefreshInterval = '00:05:00',    # Refresh every 5 minutes
    [switch]$OnTop,                             # Put the information on top
    [switch]$EnableClose,                       # Click on a visible item and click <alt>-<F4> to close
    [switch]$ShowPSWindow                       # Don't hide PowerShell window
)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationframework

$List = [Ordered]@{ # ScriptBlocks will be dynamicaly updated
    'Description'     = 'PowerShell BGInfo Example'
    1                 = '-'
    'Host Name:'      = $Env:ComputerName
    'Logon Server:'   = $Env:LogonServer
    'Pagefile:'       = { @(Get-CimInstance Win32_PageFileUsage).ForEach{ "$($_.Name) ($($_.CurrentUsage)Mb)" } }
    'IP Addres:'      = { (Get-CimInstance Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'IPEnabled="true"').IPAddress.Where{ $_ -Match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}' } }
    'OS:'             = (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
    'Boot Time:'      = (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
    'Free Space:'     = { @(Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk).ForEach{ "$($_.DeviceID) $(Format-ByteSize $_.FreeSpace)" } -Join ', ' }
}

$Xaml = [xml](@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Window FontFamily="Calibri, Arial" FontSize="14" TextElement.Foreground="White"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="SSO_BGInfo" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized" ShowInTaskbar="False" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Window.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0"/>
    </Window.Background>
    <WrapPanel Margin="40" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="List">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="40" />
        <!-- Control bar spacer in case aligned to bottom -->
    </WrapPanel>
</Window>
'@)

$Script:User32 = Add-Type -Debug:$False -MemberDefinition '
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindow(int handle, int state);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
' -Name "User32Functions" -namespace User32Functions -PassThru

if (!$ShowPSWindow) { [Void]($User32::ShowWindow((Get-Process -id $PID).MainWindowHandle, 0)) }

$Processes = @(Get-CimInstance win32_process -Filter "name='powershell.exe'").Where{
    (Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $_ -MethodName GetOwner).User -eq $Env:Username
}
$MyProcess = $Processes.Where{ $_.ProcessId -eq $PID }
if ($MyProcess.CommandLine) {
    $Processes.Where{
        $_.ProcessName -eq $MyProcess.ProcessName -and
        $_.CommandLine -eq $MyProcess.CommandLine -and
        $_.ProcessId -ne $MyProcess.ProcessId
    }.ForEach{
        Stop-Process $_.ProcessId
    }
}

$Script:Shlwapi = Add-Type -MemberDefinition '
    [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]public static extern int StrFormatByteSize(long fileSize, System.Text.StringBuilder pwszBuff, int cchBuff);
' -Name "ShlwapiFunctions" -namespace ShlwapiFunctions -PassThru

function Script:Format-ByteSize([Long]$Size) {
    $Bytes = New-Object Text.StringBuilder 20
    $Return = $Shlwapi::StrFormatByteSize($Size, $Bytes, $Bytes.Capacity)
    if ($Return) {$Bytes.ToString()}
}

function Script:Update {
    $Handle = [System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper]::new($Script:Window).Handle
    $InsertAfter = if ($OnTop) { -1 } else { 1 }
    [Void]$Script:User32::SetWindowPos($Handle, $InsertAfter, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x53)

    $Script:Dynamic.GetEnumerator().ForEach{
        $Value = &$_.Value.Tag
        if ($_.Value.Text -cne $Value) { # Only update UI when required
            $_.Value.Text = $Value
        }
    }
}

$Script:Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader($Xaml)))

$Script:Dynamic = @{}
$Grid = $Window.FindName('List')
$Row = 0
$List.GetEnumerator().ForEach{
    $Grid.RowDefinitions.add([System.Windows.Controls.RowDefinition]::new())
    if ($_.Value -Match '^\s*-+\s*') {
        $Separator = [System.Windows.Controls.Separator]::new()
        $Grid.AddChild($Separator)
        [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetRow($Separator, $Row)
        [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumn($Separator, 0)
        [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumnSpan($Separator, 99)
    }
    else {
        $TextBlock = [System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock]@{ Text = $_.Name; TextAlignment = 'Right' }
        $Grid.AddChild($TextBlock)
        [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetRow($TextBlock, $Row)
        [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumn($TextBlock, 0)
        if ($_.Value -is [ScriptBlock]) {
            $TextBlock = [System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock]@{ Tag = $_.Value }
            $Script:Dynamic[$_.Name] = $TextBlock
        }
        else {
            $TextBlock = [System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock]@{ Text = $_.Value }
        }
        $Grid.AddChild($TextBlock)
        [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetRow($TextBlock, $Row)
        [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumn($TextBlock, 2)
    }
    $Row++
}

$Script:Window.Add_Loaded({ Update })
$Script:Window.Add_Activated({ Update })
if (!$EnableClose) { $Script:Window.Add_Closing({ $_.Cancel = $True }) }
$Timer = [System.Windows.Forms.Timer]::new()
$Timer.Interval = ([TimeSpan]$RefreshInterval).TotalMilliseconds
$Timer.Add_Tick({ Update })
$Timer.Start()
[Void]$Script:Window.ShowDialog()
$Timer.Stop()
$Timer.Dispose()
```

Usage

```
.\BGInfo.ps1
```

For troubleshooting and debugging, use the command:

```
.\BGInfo.ps1 -EnableClose -ShowPSWindow
```

Comment: But where''s the HTML? Besides the immediate desire to replace bginfo, I want to use it in a regular basis to throw HTML at it and make it pop up from PowerShell.  Isn't there some way we can get to the DOM of a WebBrowser object in the XAML and either document.write or set innerHTML to a block of HTML?   -- like just display the results of string '<h1>Aloha</h1>' to start with.

Comment: If not using HTML, it's easier to transpose the objects and ogv the result. It is possible to put a WebBrowser object on a Form and get HTML output by controlling documentText, but then it doesn't resize automatically.

Comment: function Transpose { process { $_.psObject.properties|Select name,value } }; $(ForEach ($thing in @('OperatingSystem', 'ComputerSystemProduct','PhysicalMemory')) {Get-CimInstance -ClassName "Win32_$thing" | transpose}) | ogv